# angular how to prevent user typing url directly to access pages when he is logout

Tags: angularjs

I am using `$stateProvider`, so I have lots of states.

considering below scenario:
user is already logout, and he types url in the browser directly, like `www.example.com/home`, I should redirect it to the login page, which is `www.example.com/login`

how to implement this? one of the methods is to check if the session is active in run block. is it a good practice to call backend API in the run block?

**UPDATE**:
According to Ryan's suggestion, it calls backend api to check if user is logged in

```
$transitions.onBefore({to: 'home'}, function(transition) {
        var $state = transition.router.stateService;
        let promise = jsonService.heartBeat()
        promise.then(data => {
            if(!data.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
                $state.go('login')
            }
        }, () => {
            $state.go('login') 
        })
    });
```

Comment: This question is *way* too broad for StackOverflow but it's surely been done before.

Comment: @Phil, can you give some ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levi's answer is correct for UI-Router pre-version 1.0. For UI-Router 1.0, the state change events such as `$stateChangeStart` are deprecated and this will no longer work. You can use the `$transitions` service instead.

```
function run ($transitions, Auth) {
  // 'to' param is the state name; 'main.**' will match 'main' and all sub-states
  $transitions.onBefore({to: 'main.**'}, function (transition) {
    var $state = transition.router.stateService;
    if (!Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      $state.go('login');
    }
  });
}

run.$inject = ['$transitions', 'Auth'];

app.run(run);
```

Comment: where can I get this 'Auth'? is it part of Angular built-in service?

Comment: Ah no, sorry, that's just a stand-in for a custom auth service. You'll have to build auth yourself which can be done with any number of libraries. My app use's JSON Web Tokens to communicate with the server. You can get an [overview of working with JWTs here](https://thinkster.io/angularjs-jwt-auth)

Comment: That's Angular-UI-Router version 0.2.x. `$transitions` is back in Angular-UI-Router version 1.0. [Here's the documentation for the service](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem months ago. Instead of using resolve, I check if the user is logged when state changes, defining run module and listening $`stateChangeStart` event, then check if the current state required authentication. If so, check if the user is logged in.

```
angular.module('portfolio.manager').config(function ($logProvider, $stateProvider) {
'use strict';

    $stateProvider
    .state('portfolio.manager', {
        url: '/manager',
        resolve: {
            portfolioAuthService: 'portfolioAuthService',

            User: function(portfolioAuthService){
              return portfolioAuthService.getUser();

            },
            Portfolios: function (User, portfolioManagerService) {
                return portfolioManagerService.getPortfolios();
            }
        },
        data: {
            requiredAuthentication: true
        },
        views: {
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/manager/portfolio-manager.html',
                controller: 'PortfolioManagerCtrl'
            },
            'no-portfolios@portfolio.manager': {
                templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/manager/partials/no-portfolios.html'
            },
            'create@portfolio.manager': {
                templateUrl: 'app/portfolio/manager/partials/create.html'
            }
        }
    })

})
.run(run);

  run.$inject = ['$rootScope','$state','loggedIn'];

  function run($rootScope,$state,loggedIn){

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(e,toState){

      if ( !(toState.data) ) return;
      if ( !(toState.data.requiredAuthentication) ) return;

      var _requiredAuthentication = toState.data.requiredAuthentication;


      if (_requiredAuthentication && !loggedIn.checkUser() ){

        e.preventDefault();
        $state.go('portfolio.login', { notify: false });
        console.log('not authorized');
      }
      return;


    });
  };
```